# MQL4: How to fetch an economic calendar's event value?

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, forex

How can I fetch the **latest** released value of an economic announcement using `MQL4` to be compared with another variable called `x`?

I need to compare the fetched data (variable `x`) with the **manually entered** variable `y` value of `170000`.

If `x > y`, a function is executed, and if `x < y` a different function is executed.

```
extern int x = 170000;

extern int y = ...; //Fetch latest value of economic announcement 
                    //to compare to extern int x

void OnStart()
  {

  if(x>y){ 
      //Executes a function
  } 

  else 
  if (x<y){
      //Executes a different function
  }

  }
```

Using `extern int`, if I set `x = 1` and `x = 3` (or any other numbers) manually, the script works correctly. I'm just wondering if `extern int` will be a suitable method to fetch a value and turn it in to a number so that I can compare them both via `x > y` or `x < y`?

I have found a SLOC from another website where somebody wanted to import a whole economic calendar in to their algorithm (despite the fact that I only require one single, latest value) which I thought may be somewhat useful to include in this question. It imports data from a `.csv` file, so maybe I could attempt this method also. The SLOC:

```
extern string HtmlAdress = "http://www.dailyfx.com/calendar/Dailyfx_Global_Economic_Calendar.csv";
```

I understand that latency will be a prominent issue with this method, **but is this possible to achieve nonetheless?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Achievable? YES:

**How?**

**`1.`** find a stable and reliable source of the published data ( delay of publication, validity of data )

**`2.`** check, how / if they operate some means of technical dissemination or remote-access to macro-data ( **`RSS`**-feed for data, not just the news-wire, flat / "ondulated" plain `html` web-table(s), statically named file updates etc. )

**`3.`** Implement a proxy-scanner, that will implement **`(2)`** autonomously to external operations of the <kbd>MetaTrader Terminal</kbd> and it's internal code-execution units.

**`4.`** Equip the **`(3)`** with an integration-ready means of protocol-agnostic, multi-platform, online communications with **`MT4`** processes ( `ZeroMQ`, `nanomsg`, et al )

**`5.`** Implement **`MT4`** `ExpertAdvisor` code to include fast and efficient communication exchange and idle-handshaking with **`proxy-scanner (3)`**.

**Tools?**

after many years doing this in large scale systems integration, the most efficient approach consists of a rapid prototyping development **`(2+3+4)`** a `python-2.x` is a reasonable option for doing this and `ZeroMQ` or `nanomsg`
provide reasonably wide ported framework for **`(4+5)`**

---

### Example? YES:

> https://www.dailyfx.com/calendar/index_iframe.html?tz=2&sort=date&week=today&eur=true&usd=true&jpy=true&gbp=true&chf=true&aud=true&cad=true&nzd=true&cny=true&high=true&medium=true&low=true
> **Brings an algorithmically parse-able `html`-table as a source of the needed value(s):**
> `<tr class   ="e-cal-row"
>      id      ="eventrow10"
>      onClick ="commentOnOff('...xml',10,'english')">
>   <td></td>
>   <td>`**`10:00`**`</td>
>   <td><div class="flag-32-eur"></div></td>
>   <td width="100%">`**`EUR German IFO - Expectations (AUG)`**`</td>
>   <td class="evImportance medium"><span></span></td>
>   <td style="color:red" nowrap="nowrap">
>   <span style="color:red">`**`100.1`**`</span></td>
>   <td nowrap="nowrap">`**`102.4`**`</td>
>   <td style="color:red" nowrap="nowrap">
>   <span style="color:red">`**`102.2`**`</span></td>
>   <td align="right"><div class="arrow"></div></td>
>   </tr>`

### Risky? YES:

- more components means more places to implement error-recovery strategies
- solution is ultimately dependent on the state of **`(2)`** ( implementing 1+1 source of updates possible )
- finally, any tiny change in **`(2)`** renders your processing line to stop and enforces your implementation to loop back to **`(2)`** and **re**-starts **re**-engineering, **re**-implementation and **re**-testing steps again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I may have found a method to do this by importing data from a website which provides CSV format API calls, which I will fetch using MQL4's WebRequest() function.

Comment: This would be fine to fit into **`(2)`**. But one should also note, that in case such link for a file with Fundamental Data announcements indeed exists and works ( the one above does not ), the `.CSV` file requires content parsing and additional processing to get individual value. The **`WebRequest()`** function will not help you in any case, other ports than a `port# == { 80 | 443 }` are required for interactions by **`httpServer`**.